On an Atiyah-Singer-Patodi like construction of the spectral flow
Let $\hat{\mathfrak{F}}$ be the space of selfadjoint Fredholm operators on a separable infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $H$, and let $\hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0\subset\hat{\mathfrak{F}}$ consist of the strongly indefinite operators. The space $\hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0$ is a classifying space for the functor $K^{-1}(-)$ (Atiyah and Singer, Index Theory for Skew-Adjoint Fredholm Operators). Based on this fact,
a description of the spectral flow of closed paths
$F:[0,1]\rightarrow \hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0$ was given by
Atiyah, Singer and Patodi (Spectral Assymetry and Riemannian Geometry. III.): it corresponds to the composition
$${\rm sf}:[S^1 , \hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0]\rightarrow K^{-1}(S^1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},$$
where the second arrow is the isomorphism given by the first Chern class. I would like to obtain a similar description of the specral flow for paths $F:[0,1]\rightarrow\hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0$ not necessarily closed, but with invertible endpoints $F(0)$ and $F(1)$. For instance, onde could try to complete such a path to a closed one, $\tilde{F}$, by connecting $F(1)$ to $F(0)$ within $\hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0\cap GL(H)$, and then computing ${\rm sf}(\tilde{F})$. But this raises the question of wether
$\hat{\mathfrak{F}}_0\cap GL(H)$ is connected and simply connected, to which I don't know the answer. Is the answer positive? Is there an Atiyah-Singer-Patodi like construction for the spectral flow of such paths?
